# How create array title in json FROM SQL?

Tags: c#, json

Currently, my result is like this:

```
[    
      {  
         "ib_itemcode1":"0 ",
         "transtatuscode":"IN",
         "invtid":"02007997 ",
         "descr":"Pantene C/C Intensive Care Mask 6 x 150m "
      },
      {  
         "ib_itemcode1":"12 ",
         "transtatuscode":"12",
         "invtid":"12 ",
         "descr":"12 "
      },
      {  
         "ib_itemcode1":"1232131 ",
         "transtatuscode":"ss",
         "invtid":"123123 ",
         "descr":"qweqweqwe "
      },
      {  
         "ib_itemcode1":"13 ",
         "transtatuscode":"13",
         "invtid":"13 ",
         "descr":"13 "
      },
      {  
         "ib_itemcode1":"47400179172 ",
         "transtatuscode":"IN",
         "invtid":"13101336 ",
         "descr":"Gillette Mach 3 Dispenser 8S (X12) "
      },
      {  
         "ib_itemcode1":"47400179349 ",
         "transtatuscode":"IN",
         "invtid":"13101473 ",
         "descr":"Gillette Mach3 Cart 4S (X12) "
      }
]
```

how do I set a product title so that it will look something like this

```
[  
 "Product":[
   {  
      "ib_itemcode1":"0 ",
      "transtatuscode":"IN",
      "invtid":"02007997 ",
      "descr":"Pantene C/C Intensive Care Mask 6 x 150m "
   },
   {  
      "ib_itemcode1":"12 ",
      "transtatuscode":"12",
      "invtid":"12 ",
      "descr":"12 "
   },
   {  
      "ib_itemcode1":"1232131 ",
      "transtatuscode":"ss",
      "invtid":"123123 ",
      "descr":"qweqweqwe "
   },
   {  
      "ib_itemcode1":"13 ",
      "transtatuscode":"13",
      "invtid":"13 ",
      "descr":"13 "
   },
   {  
      "ib_itemcode1":"47400179172 ",
      "transtatuscode":"IN",
      "invtid":"13101336 ",
      "descr":"Gillette Mach 3 Dispenser 8S (X12) "
   },
   {  
      "ib_itemcode1":"47400179349 ",
      "transtatuscode":"IN",
      "invtid":"13101473 ",
      "descr":"Gillette Mach3 Cart 4S (X12) "
   }
           ]
]
```

The way I pull all these is from SQL server.

I had two projects in a Solution for visual studio.

1. ProductDataAccess (database)
2. ProcuctServiceFinal (The codes to create Rest services)

In (1)

```
namespace ProductDataAccess
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class product
{
    public string ib_itemcode1 { get; set; }
    public string transtatuscode { get; set; }
    public string invtid { get; set; }
    public string descr { get; set; }
}
}
```

Where or how should I go or add the title?

Comment: Which programming language is that?

Comment: That is C#. Judging from the combination of partial classes, automatic properties and .NET namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first output is not correct JSON, as an array has no properties. You probably mean `{ "Product": [...] }` instead of `[ "Product": [...] ]`. With curly braces instead of square bracket it is the serialization output of an object of this class:

```
class MyJsonClass {
    public product[] Product { get; set; }
}
```

Which you would instantiate like this  (assuming you have the variables `product1` to `product6` with the desired content):

```
MyJsonClass itemToSerialize = new MyJsonClass() {
    Product = { product1, product2, product3, product4, product5, product6 }
};
```

If you want an output like your second exaple you need to serialize an array of `product`:

```
product[] itemToSerialize = { product1, product2, product3, product4, product5, product6 };
```

Comment: hi sir, thanks for the reply. after some one edit my code i think they mess up some part. what i meant was. my json does not have "Product": [...], its just a chunk of [...] how do i add that "Product" <= into my json code so that it looks like what you ment.